# Разбор даты

Tags: дата, javascript

Добрый день. Как на javascript распарсить строку даты в формате dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var a = '12.34.5678 90:12';
var m = a.match(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
m[1]; // dd
m[2]; // mm
m[3]; // yyyy
m[4]; // hh
m[5]; // mm
```